Какая универсальная фаловая структура должна быть проекта?
Пишу пока что на html css js после окончательного написание проекта планирую подключить препроцессор и фреймворк react.
Озадачиваюсь вопросом, какую фаловую стуру сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Возьмите сразу что-нибудь типа Vite он вам сам структуру всю сделает как надо

Могу рекомендовать fractal project structure и монорепозиторий для Webpack module federation

Пример подобного проекта можно посмотреть в GitHub репозитории

├── src                       # Application source code
│   ├── components            # Reusable Presentational Components
│   ├── assets                # Required assets
│   ├── layouts               # Components that dictate major page structure
│   └── routes                # Main route definitions and async split points
│       ├── index.js          # Bootstrap main application routes with store
│       │
│       └── Route1
│       │    ├── index.js     # Route definitions and async split points
│       │    ├── components   # Presentational React Components
│       │    ├── assets       # Assets required to render components
│       │
│       └── Route2
│       │    ├── index.js     # Route definitions and async split points
│       │    ├── components   # Presentational React Components
│       │    ├── assets       # Assets required to render components

